# How to return a function in scheme (racket) using conditionals?

Tags: scheme, racket

How do I return a function using conditionals in scheme? What I want to do is to return the product of 2 numbers (when r = 0), or the sum (when r=1) or the difference (when r=2) or 0 (otherwise) depending on the value of r.

What I tried is below, but the return value is always 0. How do I fix that?

```
    (define (f r)( lambda (x y)
      (cond (equal? r 0) 
          ((* x y))
      ( (equal? r 1)
          ( (+ x y)))
      ( (equal? r 2))
          ( (- x y))
      (else
          0 ))))

(( f 0) 2 3)
```

I would expect 6, but I get 0. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The correct result is `0`. The first predicate `equal?` is never `#f` so the last expression, `0`, is the only outcome of the `cond`. Note that you are chcking if `equal?` is true, not if `(equal? r 0)` is true.

Comment: Perhaps you should try to format your code better to make it easier to spot mistakes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`cond`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html?q=cond#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._cond%29%29) works like this:

```
(cond (test-expr then-body) 
      (test-expr2 then-body2)
      (else then-body3))
```

The test-exprs are tested one by one, and the first test-expr that returns a non-false value causes its corresponding then-body to be executed. The last value in the executed then-body is the value of the whole `cond`.

To know why you got `0` (and not `6`), look carefully at your first `cond` clause: `(cond (equal? r 0) ...)`. `equal?` is the test-expr, and since `equal?` itself is not false, its then-body is executed (i.e. `r` and `0` are executed). Since `0` is the last value in the then-body, `0` is the value of the whole `cond`. That's why you got `0`.

Note that nearly all lines in your `cond` have parentheses that have been incorrectly placed. Here's a fixed version:

```
(define (f r)
  (lambda (x y)
    (cond ((equal? r 0)  ; <- Parentheses fixed.
           (* x y))      ; <- Parentheses fixed.
          ((equal? r 1)  ; <- Parentheses fixed.
           (+ x y))      ; <- Parentheses fixed.
          ((equal? r 2)  ; <- Parentheses fixed.
           (- x y))      ; <- Parentheses fixed.
          (else 0))))
```

Here's an arguably better way to define the same function:

```
(define (f r)
  (cond ((= r 0) *)
        ((= r 1) +)
        ((= r 2) -)
        (else (lambda _ 0))))
```

For example:

```
((f 0) 2 3)
;; '(f 0)' returns '*', so this reduces to: (* 2 3)
;; Answer:
6
```

This version is technically better as it is not restricted to taking only two arguments. For example, you can now do this: `((f 1) 1 2 3 4 5 6)` (reduces to `(+ 1 2 3 4 5 6)`).

Comment: Bravo! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `cond` expression in your code has some syntax errors:

- There are brackets missing in each condition
- You must not surround a procedure application with double brackets, this is a mistake: `((* x y))`

Notice that you require to return an arithmetic *procedure* and, for example, we can simply return `+` which is similar to returning `(lambda (x y) (+ x y))` (except that it'll work for more than two parameters, but that's a win!).

Bear in mind that in Racket the solution can be written in a more concise way: for example, by using `case` to simplify the conditions and `const` for the last case, when we want to return a procedure that returns `0` no matter what are the parameters. Here's how:

```
(define (f r)
  (case r
    ((0) *)
    ((1) +)
    ((2) -)
    (else (const 0))))
```

It works as expected, by returning a procedure that you can apply to the given arguments:

```
((f 0) 6 7)
=> 42
((f 3) 2 3)
=> 0
```